# Loro sono dei poliziotti statali vs Loro sono poliziotti statali

Tags: difference, articles

I have read the following sentence in a Italian learning tool:

> Loro sono dei poliziotti statali.

"They are some state police officers" is not usual in English in this neutral context, so I'd rather translate that sentence to "They are state police officers". So, I wonder: what is the difference between the above sentence and "Loro sono poliziotti statali" ?

Comment: The Italian sentences sound quite stilted too, in either form... For one, _poliziotti statali_ is a curious hybrid of colloquial and formal; you'd either say _poliziotti_ (nobody talks of _poliziotti comunali_, say) or _agenti della Polizia di Stato_ (or more likely, simply _agenti di polizia_).

Comment: @DaG: Anyway, the question would be if there is any difference between "sono poliziotti" e "sono dei poliziotti".

Comment: Yes, @Charo, mine was just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking about the use of articles in Italian, in his book *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto*, Vittorio Coletti explains that the so called "articolo partitivo" ("dei", "degli" or "delle") is used to make the plural of an indeterminative article, but that such a plural is also frequently expressed by simply omitting the article:

> L'articolo partitivo funge anche da plurale dell'indeterminativo, quando il plurale è ammissibile, ovviamente: «voglio una torta» e «voglio delle torte». Un plurale indeterminato è spesso dato anche solo dall'assenza di articolo; la frase «ci sono studenti» è uguale a «ci sono degli studenti» ed entrambe sono diverse da «ci sono gli studenti».

So, as in the example given by Coletti («ci sono studenti» is the same as «ci sono degli studenti»), both the sentences «sono poliziotti» and «sono dei poliziotti» are correct and mean the same.

Answer (score -1):

To express someone's profession, you would usually say:

```
{subject} {to be} {profession}
example: Io sono professore di italiano.
```

To express the profession or quality of an unnumbered subset of people in a numbered group of people you would usually say:

```
{subject (subset of a bigger group)} {to be} {articolo partitivo} {profession/quality/characteristic}
```

The same form can be used to express a quality:

```
{subject} {to be} {articolo partitivo} {profession/quality/characteristic}
example: Puoi fidarti di Luca e Paolo, sono dei bravi ragazzi.
```

An "articolo partitivo" is the combination of the preposition "di" and a definite article. It is used to express an undetermined quantity of something in a group. You can also find it used as the plural form of the indeterminate article it is composed of.

In your example, if the intention was to express the profession of the subject "loro", `loro sono poliziotti` is the correct form. Still, you can hear `loro sono dei poliziotti` used to express a profession.

`loro sono dei poliziotti` would be correct if `dei` was actually used as a *partitivo*, to indicate that "some guys in a counted group of people" are *poliziotti*.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: “loro sono poliziotti is the correct form”: So you think the other one isn't?

Comment: In this kind of sentences, _dei_ is more precisely called an _articolo partitivo_ (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/articolo-partitivo_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/).

Comment: @DaG you're right about the partitivo, answer updated. Still, i'd say the correct form is the one without 'dei' if the intention is to express the profession or activity of the subject

Comment: Could you clarify why “dei” would be incorrect, gives as it is a regular Italian _articolo partitivo_?

Comment: @DaG _partitivi_ should be used to express an undetermined quantity of something in an enumerated group. To express a profession/employment, no article should be used. Now that i think about it, the context of the phrase might have actually been to indicate that some guys in a group of people are _poliziotti_, even if it still sounds 'stiff' to me... If that phrase was actually used to explain articoli partitivi, i think that's a bad example, even with a given context. Without a context it's just misleading. Anyway, i'll update my answer to include the possibility.

Comment: Passiamo all'italiano, così ci capiamo meglio. Mi sembra che non ti sia molto chiaro l'uso del partitivo. In italiano ha un uso molto più ampio rispetto a quello che sembri descrivere tu, anche al plurale, dove fa di fatto da plurale dell'articolo indeterminativo. Vedi per esempio http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/partitivo_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/, la risposta qui http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/partitivo_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/, la grammatica del Serianni e qualunque altra grammatica seria.